# Apollo's useQuery doesn't seem to be executing at all, how can I turn on debug statements or something for Apollo client?

Tags: typescript, react-native, apollo-client

I have the Apollo client configured as per the docs, using the `ApolloProvider` so that I may be able to use `useQuery` in nested components. When I run queries using the `apolloClient` that is provided to the `ApolloProvider`, I.e.:

```js
apolloClient.query({query, variables});
```

queries work just fine. However, in a screen further down the tree I have something like the following:

```js
export default function SomeScreen({ route }: RouteProps) {
  ...
  let query: DocumentNode;
  switch (route.params.someParam) {
    case 'A':
      query = someQuery1;
      break;
    ...
    default:
      query = someQueryX;
  }

  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery<{myData: SomeType[]}, QueryArgTypes>(
    query,
    {variables}, //assigned elsewhere but they're constant
  );

  if (loading) return <Text>Loading</Text>
  if (error) return <Text>Error</Text>
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data?.myData}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (<SomeComp elem={item} />)}
      keyExtractor={(item) => (
        item._id!.toString()
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

However, in this case, the `if (loading)` branch is just always true. Furthermore, the `uri` I used when instantiating `apolloClient` is one which is part of the project I'm working on. I was able to set break points in it to pause execution when my `query` executes, and it never reaches any of the breakpoints I've set at all. So as far as I can tell, `useQuery` isn't even trying to execute the query (never makes it to the backend) but I don't get any description of what's going on. Anyone have any idea what might be happening? Some relevant dependencies are:

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"@apollo/client": "^3.6.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't know what that issue might be, but here's an example so you can make sure you have the proper set up of the client:

***client.js***

```js
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: URL_GRAPHQL,
});

const authLink = setContext( async (_, { headers })  => {

  const token = await getTokenService()
    
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});


export default client
```

***App.tsx***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';

import AppRouter from './src/routes/AppRouter';
import client from './src/graphql/client';

export default function App() {

  return (
                
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      
      <StatusBar barStyle='light-content'/>
      <AppRouter />
      
    </ApolloProvider>
    
    
  );
  
}
```

***Child component:***

```js
const ListScreen : React.FC<IProps> = ( { route } ) => {
  
  let listId                              = route.params.listId;
  const styles                            = useStyles()
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery<ListResponse>(GET_LIST_ById, { variables: { listId } });
  
  return (
     <view>
     </view>
  )
  
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I pretty much have exactly this going but I think I encountered a known (yet not openly discussed bug), this SO answer solved it for me in case anyone else encounters this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083468/loading-remains-true-when-loading-data-with-usequery-using-apolloclient-in

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was a known bug. In case anyone else encounters this, upgrading to the beta solved it for me:

['loading' remains true when loading data with 'useQuery' using 'apolloClient' in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083468/loading-remains-true-when-loading-data-with-usequery-using-apolloclient-in)