# Apollo client useQuery hook stuck at loading state for queries

Tags: typescript, react-native, graphql, apollo

I am trying to make api calls using the `useQuery` hook of @apollo/client but the loading props of the query is always `true` so the `Loader` is always shown. I first tried this by calling multiple `useQuery` hooks one after another, but later found out that even a single query execution is giving this state. I am sharing the relevant details below. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083468/loading-remains-true-when-loading-data-with-usequery-using-apolloclient-in) answer but it spoke about versioning, which is not solving my problem. Here are my code, dependencies and details about where I am calling this hook.

`Home.tsx`

```
// necessary imports
import * as query from 'queries';
import {useQuery} from '@apollo/client';

let obj = {
  "Skin":"",
  "Hair":"",
  "Beard":"",
  "Wellness":"",
  "Performance":""
}

const encode = (str:string):string => Buffer.from(str,'binary').toString('base64');

const Home = () => {
  const queryString = query.GET_COLLECTIONS_BY_HANDLE;

  const hair = useQuery(queryString.query,{
      variables:{
        handle:'hair'
      }
  });

  const skin = useQuery(queryString.query,{
    variables:{
      handle:'skin'
    }
  });

  const beard = useQuery(queryString.query,{
    variables:{
      handle:'beard'
    }
  });

  const wellness = useQuery(queryString.query,{
    variables:{
      handle:'wellness'
    }
  });

  const performance = useQuery(queryString.query,{
    variables:{
      handle:'performance'
    }
  });

  if(hair.loading || skin.loading || wellness.loading || performance.loading || beard.loading){
    console.log('Loading hair',hair.loading);
    console.log('Loading skin',skin.loading);
    console.log('Loading wellness',wellness.loading);
    console.log('Loading beard',beard.loading);
    console.log('Loading performance',performance.loading);
    return <Loader/> // This is my custom Activity Indicator
  }

  if(hair.error || wellness.error || skin.error || performance.error || beard.error){
    console.error(hair.error);
  }
  
  if(hair.data != undefined){
    obj['Hair'] = hair.data.id;
  }

  if(skin.data != undefined){
    obj['Skin'] = skin.data.id;
  }


  if(wellness.data != undefined){
    obj['Wellness'] = wellness.data.id;
  }

  if(performance.data != undefined){
    obj['Performance'] = performance.data.id;
  }

  if(beard.data != undefined){
    obj['Beard'] = beard.data.id;
  }

    return (
      //rendering the UI
  )
}

export default Home
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.7",
     //other packages
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "ts-mixer": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //development Dependencies
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Navigation structure : Drawer on Top -> Tab Navigation -> Stack Navigation.

When the App loads, the first screen shown in Home.tsx and the loader is continuously shown.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my question

Comment: Don't you have any error in the debug console? It looks like the problem may be an error in the API call. Try to move the errors displaying on top of the loader block.

Comment: Not really, after doing some changes (for ex: adding a space) and saving, the data is loaded successfully (that too sometimes) :-/ This is another weird behavior that I can't understand.

Comment: Using `useQuery` more than once in a component is an anti-pattern. You can run all those queries at once and only have one loading state. Much faster and cleaner. [example](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/multiple-queries-in-a-single-graphql-request)

Comment: @MichelFloyd can you put that as an answer? The example you linked helped my case. I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using useQuery more than once in a component is an anti-pattern. You can run all those queries at once and only have one loading state. Simpler, faster, cleaner.

Example:

```
query twoQueries($p1: string!, $p2: string!) {
  query1(p1: $p1) {
    field1
    field2
    …
  }
  query2(p2: $p2) {
    fieldA
    fieldB
    …
  }
}
```

[In depth blog post on this topic](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/multiple-queries-in-a-single-graphql-request)